# Lisp - Sort using custom function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this function in Lisp:

```
(defun AddtoQueue (queue method)
  (cond
    ( (eq method 'DFS) (append (growPath (car queue)  (findCh (caar queue))) (cdr queue) ) )
    ( (eq method 'BFS) (append (cdr queue) (growPath (car queue)(findCh (caar queue))) ) )
    ( (eq method 'A) (SORT  (append (cdr queue) (growPath (car queue) (findCh (caar queue)) ) ) #'> :key #'pathLength  ) )
    (T "not implemented")
  )
)
```

I have to sort a list using a custom function (here named `pathLength` ) . I read lisp's documentation about `sort` but i can't understand a thing. My question is what exactly am i feeding my comparison function?

Comparison function:

```
(defun pathLength(point)

    ;;distance from origin point
    (setq x (- (length queue) 1) ) 

    ;;distance from end(manhattan distance) by subtracting the coords.
    ;;calc lists is adding or subtracting lists.
    (setq y (calcLists (cadr (assoc (car point) coords)) (cadr (assoc terminal coords)) 'sub ) )


    (setq y (+ (car y) (cadr y) ) )
    ;;sum of distance from start and end.
    (+ x y)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison function (which in this case is `>`) gets two arguments (two elements being compared). The arguments will go through the key function (`pathLength`) before being compared. You can use [`TRACE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm) to see what the functions are called with. For example:

```
(trace >)
;=> (>)
(sort (list 4 5 1) #'>)
;  0: (> 5 4)
;  0: > returned T
;  0: (> 1 4)
;  0: > returned NIL
;=> (5 4 1)
(trace 1+)
;=> (1+)
(sort (list 4 5 1) #'> :key #'1+)
;  0: (1+ 5)
;  0: 1+ returned 6
;  0: (1+ 4)
;  0: 1+ returned 5
;  0: (> 6 5)
;  0: > returned T
;  0: (1+ 1)
;  0: 1+ returned 2
;  0: (1+ 4)
;  0: 1+ returned 5
;  0: (> 2 5)
;  0: > returned NIL
;=> (5 4 1)
(untrace > 1+)
;=> T
```

A few comments about your code.

1. In Lisps, the naming convention for functions and variables is to use all lower-case with dashes between words. So `add-to-queue` instead of `AddtoQueue`. The names (symbols) are usually automatically converted to upper-case (and written so in comments and such), but when writing actual code you should use lower-case.
2. You shouldn't put the closing paren on its own line. Use linebreaks and indentation to show the structure of the program.
3. Local variables should be defined using [`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) instead of `SETQ`.
4. Since the `COND` in `ADD-TO-QUEUE` is only comparing if `METHOD` is `EQ` to a symbol, [`CASE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm) would be better suited for the task.
5. Your `PATH-LENGTH` is using the variable `QUEUE`, which is local to `ADD-TO-QUEUE`. You need to move the function inside the same scope by using [`FLET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm).
6. It's also using variables called `TERMINAL` and `COORDS`, which don't seem to exist in either of the functions. If those are global (special) variables (which should be defined using [`DEFVAR` or `DEFPARAMETER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm)), you should add earmuffs (asterisks) around the names to show that: `*TERMINAL*`, `*COORDS*`.

I can't test this without the full code, but the code should look something like this:

```
(defun add-to-queue (queue method)
  (flet ((path-length (point)
           (let* ((x (1- (length queue)))
                  ;; It's better to use FIRST and SECOND instead of CAR and
                  ;; CADR when dealing with lists.
                  (temp (calc-lists (second (assoc (car point) *coords*))
                                    (second (assoc *terminal* *coords*))
                                    'sub))
                  (y (+ (first temp) (second temp))))
             (+ x y))))
    (case method
      (DFS
       ;; Consider using full words for function names. So
       ;; FIND-CHARACTER, assuming that's what CH means.
       (append (grow-path (car queue)
                          (find-ch (caar queue)))
               (cdr queue)))
      (BFS
       (append (cdr queue)
               (grow-path (car queue)
                          (find-ch (caar queue)))))
      (A
       (sort (append (cdr queue)
                     (grow-path (car queue)
                                (find-ch (caar queue))))
             #'> :key #'path-length))
      ;; You could use `ECASE` to automatically signal an error
      ;; if METHOD doesn't match any of the cases.
      (otherwise "not implemented"))))
```

Comment: Perfect Answer, thanks you. You pointed more things that i was waiting to get. Only been using Lisp for  a month.